# Rails history.pushState to show URL via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to show the URL using history.pushState. Inside my `assets/javascript/application.js` I place the ff codes:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagination a.page-link[data-remote=true]', function(){
    alert('voila');
    history.pushState({}, '', $(this).attr('href'));  
});
```

This code did not run even my alert.

Here's what I am trying to pull with click function:

[image]

As you can see I am trying to access the anchor tag that has the data-remote inside it but it doesn't work.

The expected output I am trying to attain is that whenever I click on one pagination it must show the page number like `http://localhost:3000/contacts?page=2` inside the URL bar at the top.

[image]

How do I make this work?

Comment: Is `data-remote` set by default on `<a>` tag? or add on a event after?

Comment: yes it was set by default `<%= paginate @contacts, remote: true %>` (I've added inside Kaminari pagination gem which works just fine but the page url doesnt show up still w/o refresh)

Comment: Any error in your console?

Comment: Nope the are no errors in the console.

Comment: Nope. It did not work

Answer (score 0):

I think it's wokring but since you didn't prevent `href` it redirect to your url. you need to use `e.preventDefault()` to avoid redirect to your `href` url, now it should work:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.pagination a.page-link[data-remote=true]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //history.pushState({}, '', $(this).attr('href'));  
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination">
<a class="page-link" data-remote="true" href="stackoverflow.com">Click</a>
</div>
```

*Note: `pushState` not work here for security reason!*

Comment: Pedram. It did not work. I tried it but the same, no alert showed up either.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
window.history.pushState(history.state, null, $(this).attr('href'));
```

Comment: This did not work either. It's not even showing up the alert.